# Fetch data from google analytics programmatically

Tags: grails

i am new to grails,  I want to retrive data from my google analytics account programmatically using grails    -i am a building project where i need to track of all hits of user into my website.  how can in do this,  i need it because i need to track user hits into my website.any help will be great.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps all you need is the plugin? http://grails.org/plugin/google-analytics

Comment: Also I can share with my custom plugin for yandex